# Get Data from Mysql Android

Tags: java, android, mysql, json, android-asynctask

I have a problem. I want to get data from my mysql database using PhP but I get theese errors :

> org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of  W/System.err:     at
>   org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:450) W/System.err:
>   at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:97) W/System.err:
>   at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:156) W/System.err:
>   at org.json.JSONObject.(JSONObject.java:173) W/System.err:
>   at
>   neimantasjocius.com.justbeontop.LoginActivity.returnPoints(LoginActivity.java:123)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   neimantasjocius.com.justbeontop.LoginActivity.access$100(LoginActivity.java:27)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   neimantasjocius.com.justbeontop.LoginActivity$AsyncDataClass.onPostExecute(LoginActivity.java:99)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   neimantasjocius.com.justbeontop.LoginActivity$AsyncDataClass.onPostExecute(LoginActivity.java:68)
>   W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177) W/System.err:
>   at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) W/System.err:
>   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) W/System.err:     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5272)
>   W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>   W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
>   W/System.err:     at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
>   W/ResourceType: No package identifier when getting value for resource
>   number 0x00000000 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: neimantasjocius.com.justbeontop, PID:
>   30041 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource
>   ID #0x0 at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:275)
>   at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4261) at
>   neimantasjocius.com.justbeontop.LoginActivity$AsyncDataClass.onPostExecute(LoginActivity.java:101)
>   at
>   neimantasjocius.com.justbeontop.LoginActivity$AsyncDataClass.onPostExecute(LoginActivity.java:68)
>   at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632) at
>   android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177) at
>   android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5272) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)

Here is the code I use : **I marked the line Numbers where error is given.**

```
private final String serverUrl = "http://*******.***";      // <---- 27

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle intentBundle = intent.getExtras();
    String loggedUser = intentBundle.getString("USERNAME");
    loggedUser = capitalizeFirstCharacter(loggedUser);

    TextView loginUsername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login_user);

    loginUsername.setText(loggedUser);
    AsyncDataClass asyncRequestObject = new AsyncDataClass();
    asyncRequestObject.execute(serverUrl);
}
private class AsyncDataClass extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);

        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(params[0]);

        String PointsString = "";
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            PointsString = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return PointsString;
    }                       // <---- 68
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        int points = returnPoints(result);
        TextView pointsText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pointsText);
        pointsText.setText(points);

    }
    private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String rLine = "";
        StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        try {
            while ((rLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                answer.append(rLine);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return answer;
    }
}
private int returnPoints(String result){
    JSONObject resultObject = null;
    int returnedPoints = 0;
    try {                                            // <----- 99
        resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
        returnedPoints = resultObject.getInt("points");       // <--- 101
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return returnedPoints;
}
private String capitalizeFirstCharacter(String textInput){
    String input = textInput.toLowerCase();
    String output = input.toUpperCase();
    return output;
}     // <-- Actually its 113 but error is given at 123
```

Comment: Try to print the raw JSON. Looks like its blank.

Comment: Initialize your `pointsText` TextView in `onCreate()`.

Comment: When I initialize pointsText in onCreate the new error come.

Comment: What is it? Do you have the TextView element in the xml?

Comment: Can you print raw JSON in doInBackground{ .... Log.d("raw result", PointsString.toString()); return PointsString; }